# How to attach email to crash logs on HockeyApp

Tags: uwp, hockeyapp, windows-community-toolkit

How can I attach the login information(only E-mail ID) in the crash logs for my UWP application on HockeyApp. I wish to do this so that I can associate the user information of the testers of my application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The HockyApp SDK has a [user info API](https://support.hockeyapp.net/kb/client-integration-windows-and-windows-phone/how-to-instrument-applications-on-windows-for-crash-reporting#user-info-api). You could use user info API to associate a crash with user email to further contain a user to get more details about the crash.

`HockeyClient.Current.UpdateContactInfo("user_id","contact_info")`